# Descartes' circle theorem problem

Tags: geometry

This problem is about Descartes' circle theorem , i solve it by different ideas but my friend said that this problem could be solved by "Descartes' circle theorem"

[image]

I read the theorm , try to apply it ; but didn't get the same result.

How could that be possible?  What i miss in understanding the theorm

Here is my solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the OP's calculation for Descartes' circle theorem it's not possible to say where the OP went wrong. Here's my calculation:

Descartes' theorem gives

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{R} & =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}\\
& =\frac{4}{3}+2\sqrt{\frac{7}{12}}\\
& =\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{21}\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{21}+4}{3}
\end{align}

and from here it's easy to show that this is the same as the OP's answer.

Note that we use the positive value from Descartes' theorem to get the radius of the small inscribed circle. Taking the negative value would give the radius of the large circumscribed circle.

Comment: thank you for help  ;  but i use the following  formula   $$( k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + k_4 )^2 = 2 ( k_1^2 + k_2^2 + k_3^2 + k_4^2 ) \qquad\text{where } k_i := \pm\frac{1}{r_i}$$
with the "$\pm$" sign indicating *internal* or *external* tangency of the corresponding circle.     Is there an differences between the two formulas ??

Comment: They're the same. What you have is the statement of the theorem. The version I used is a rearrangement that allows you to find the radius of a fourth circle if you already know the other three radii. $$k_4=k_1+k_2+k_3 \pm 2\sqrt{k_1 k_2+k_1 k_3+k_2 k_3}$$